# Accessing cgi-bin webpage from terminal

Tags: networking, lan

I have couple of Antminer L3+ running unix based OS + cgminer software. It has a password protected web interface like `http://10.12.1.1/cgi-bin/reboot.cgi` I can access it directly from a browser like this `http://root:root@10.12.1.1/cgi-bin/reboot.cgi` to reboot the device.

But when I run the same from terminal like `curl http://root:root@10.12.1.1/cgi-bin/reboot.cgi` I get 401 error.

I also tried using curl in PHP with params to mimic a browser, still getting 401 error.

Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: The whole username:password@url scheme is now non-standard. It was standard, but the propensity for related malicious attacks became so significant that a new standard developed, which was to ditch any support for the old standard. e.g., some people would create long URLs (too long to be entirely seen in a common address bar) like http://paypal.com/blah/blah%40badsite.com/blah and people would trust the URL because it started with paypal.com/, but the %40 is an @ site which turned the "paypal.com/" text into just part of a username for the badsite.com. Common fix = prohibit usernames in URLs

Comment: I understand your point, but the scope of above application is LAN and be able to automate tasks through scripts instead of browsers.

Comment: So?  If the automated tools have some similar behaviors to what browsers do, then what effect does your distinction have?  More directly: If Firefox and Chrome and Microsoft web browsers all adopt new behavior, and automated tools like cURL and WGet use the same behavior, why do you point out that you're trying to use automated tools instead of browsers? If these categories of software act the same, I'm failing to see the significance of your distinction. (Similarly: The fact you're on a LAN may mean you're actually more secure, but that doesn't mean your software isn't secure enough for WAN.)

Comment: I updated my answer with  --user 'username:password' param. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jay. Here is the working param to execute a LAN cgi-bin url like `http://root:root@10.12.1.1/cgi-bin/reboot.cgi` from terminal or by PHP script (instead of browser). This can be executed from LAN or WAN (via a pre configured port on your firewall/router).

From WAN:

```
curl --digest --user 'username:password' http://YOUR_WAN_IP:PORT/cgi-bin/reboot.cgi
```

From LAN

```
curl --digest --user 'username:password' http://YOUR_LAN_IP/cgi-bin/reboot.cgi
```

By PHP Script:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_DIGEST);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://YOUR_WAN_IP:PORT/cgi-bin/reboot.cgi');
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch)
curl_close($ch);

print_r($output);
print_r($info);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are sending the wrong authorization. Try `--digest` and if that doesn't work try [`--anyauth`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--anyauth) and use `--verbose` to figure out which one works, then find the correct auth switch in [the manual](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) and use only that one (for security).

Another thing you may want to try is enabling cookies. Some routers set cookies on 401 and expect to get that cookie back on the next request. You can read and write cookies using [`--cookie cookies.txt --cookie-jar cookies.txt`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-c). If you don't care about saving the cookies (eg you're rebooting the router) and you don't need to parse the output then `--cookie-jar -` is enough to enable the cookie engine and write them to stdout.

Comment: When I did It on FF, I see 2 lines in network tab. First one is a 401 Unauthorized and the second one is 500 Internal Server Error - but this get the machine rebooted successfully. The 500 Error's Authorization is: `Digest username="root", realm="antMiner Configuration", nonce="434d91fd2c32b977a25790d9f6b1f6af", uri="/cgi-bin/reboot.cgi", response="4fdd091fae0d7158aae7c534ee21d546", qop=auth, nc=00000001, cnonce="78e998c797d09dd0"` Can you please provide a curl param to mimic this from terminal?

Comment: This command worked!!! `curl --digest --anyauth --user 'root:root' --verbose http://10.12.1.1/cgi-bin/reboot.cgi` THANK YOU

Comment: I am glad it worked. It would help if you would upvote and mark either your answer or my answer correct so other people on the site can know this is solved without having to read the thread.

Comment: I did upvote, it has recorded but I don't have enough points for it to show.

Comment: Oh ok. I am new as well and have noticed the same thing happens to me since I have no points.